# Xcodeでビルドはできるもののシュミレーターが黒くなります。

Tags: swift, swiftui

以下のエラーの意味がわかりません。
コードは実行できるもののシュミレータは真っ黒です。
どうすれば解決できるでしょうか？是非ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

```
ailure in void __BKSHIDEvent__BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_CURRENT_PROCESS_IS_NIL__(NSBundle *__strong) (BKSHIDEvent.m:90) : missing bundleID for main bundle NSBundle
```

```
Assertion failure in -[UISApplicationStateClient initWithBundleIdentifier:], UISApplicationStateClient.m:28
```

Answer (score 1):

Bundle Identifierが空になってしまっているとかかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。bundle identifierには任意のIDを入れているんですが、エラーが出る状態です。